# Как хранить картинку в БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, node.js, sequelize.js

Подскажите пожалуйста как хранить картинку в БД MySQL? И как ее отправлять в БД и вытаскивать оттуда. Может знаете какие туториалы по данной тематике.
Создаю web-приложение для ресторана. Картинки это будут фотографии блюд. Back буду делать на Node.js.

Comment: А требование только такое - все картинки должны быть в дб? Не удобнее ли будет в таблице хранить ссылки на файлы, а файлы - в отдельной папке? Мне просто кажется, что сам принцип хранение картинок в таблице - неудобный ни для программиста, ни для клиента.

Comment: а где хранить папки?

Comment: На жёстком диске неподалеку от бд.

Answer (score 0):

Мой совет - никак :) Лучше всего хранить в БД текстовые данные и ссылки на картинки и прочие файлы. Для их хранения лучше всего воспользоваться другим решением. Например загружать их на Amazon S3.

Comment: Вопрос был "как хранить картинку в БД MySQL?" а не как лучше делать.

Answer (score 0):

Не самая гениальная идея, но вам нужно использовать тип

1. TINYBLOB 255 bytes = 0.000255 Mb
2. BLOB 65535 bytes = 0.0655 Mb
3. MEDIUMBLOB 16777215 bytes = 16.78 Mb
4. LONGBLOB 4294967295 bytes =
   4294.97 Mb = 4.295 Gb

для полей с данными файлов

Comment: а как лучше сделать?

Comment: Храните на диске, а пути в базе. В таком случае у вас не будет расти сама база данных. Имеет смысл хранить данные если вам нужно что-либо искать в этих данных, но зачастую это прос100 хранилище.